# Unwanted thin border around Container when color property is set

Tags: flutter

I've noticed a very thin border around the white border with the same color than the Container widget color property (as you can see on the screenshot below). I don't know if this "bug" comes from my code or if this is an issue with Flutter.

Do you know how can I avoid this behaviour? Otherwise, I'll build this button differently.

Here is the Container definition :

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
      border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF), width: 4.0),
      color: Colors.blue, // Here is the color that shows up
    ),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    child: AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: sizeController,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
      return CustomPaint(
        painter: CirclePainter(positionAnimation.value, sizeAnimation.value),
        child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
         children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 40.0,
              height: 40.0,
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.storefrontOutline,
                size: widget.activeIndex == 0 ? 20.0 : 12.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 40.0,
              height: 40.0,
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.homeVariant,
                size: widget.activeIndex == 1 ? 20.0 : 12.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

[Thin border around rounded container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2fB3.png)

I already tried to change radius, colors, width etc. but nothing works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are asking about the white border, it's from this line `Border.all(color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF), width: 4.0)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I know it's hard to see, but there is a pretty thin blue border outside of the white border... Hard to see but UX Designer saw it and asked me to remove it... It even looks like a shadow but when I change the background Container background color property, this weird border color changes...